# How to order a geospatial query by distance from the query point

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, geoalchemy2

I try searching for this problem on the web, but to no avail.  Seems like a basic task.  I'm using PostGresql through SQLAlchemy with Geoalchemy to do geospatial queries.  Technically, I'm using `Flask-SQLAlchemy.  I can do a geospatial query.  For example:

```
from geoalchemy2 import func
cls.db.session.query(cls).filter(func.ST_DWithin(cls.geoLoc, geo, meters))
```

where `cls` is the class I'm querying on.  `geo` is the `Geography` point representing the center of the query and `meters` is the max distance to return results from.  This query works, but returns results in an arbitrary order.  I want them returned in increasing (decreasing is fine too) distance from the query point.

I assume I need to use an `.order_by(...)` at the end of the query, but I can't figure out what to put in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out, but wow that wasn't obvious, especially if you're not intimately familiar with Geoalchemy2.

In my case above, you have to tack:

```
.order_by(func.ST_Distance(cls.geoLoc, geo))
```

to the end of the code that's in my question.  Basically, `ST_Distance` is a function that takes in a two points and returns the distance between them.  So `cls.geoLoc` refers to the each object in question from the table and `geo` is the center from which I'm sorting by distance.  This basically computes the distance for each element to `geo` and then sorts by it.